# Auth0 axios.post with token Internal Server Error 500

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, axios

I am trying to post via axios.post with token header from Auth0. I am getting the following error

[image]

Code

```
const [AccessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const token = await getAccessTokenSilently({
        audience: 'api.paintit',
        scope: 'read:posts',
      });
      setAccessToken(token);
    })();
  }, []);

axios.post(
      url,
      {data:{
        data
      }
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${AccessToken}` 
        }
      }
    ).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
```

I need to add the header to axios for logedin user. This is working for get request and for post request I am getting that error.
Please help I will be very thankful.

Comment: The error is coming from the server, while you're showing clientside code. You need to include the server code and error log in your question

Comment: I am not doing it wrong on front-end?

Comment: On server HttpError: child "userId" fails because ["userId" is required]

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.post(
      url,
        data,
      {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${AccessToken}` 
        }
      }
    ).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
```

I was add the data wrong